# Custom jQuery.validate validation rule causing the <input> after the target to become required on Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, razor, jquery-validate

I have a long form in an ASP.NET MVC application view, with a particular input "PaxCount" that needs to equal the sum of 2 other fields: AdultCount and ChildCount (I don't want to determine the value of this field automatically for other reasons).

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PaxCount, htmlAttributes: new { style = "text-align:left ", @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-2 input-group">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PaxCount, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "0", style = "width:70px;", @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PaxCount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdultCount, htmlAttributes: new { style = "text-align:left", @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-2 input-group">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdultCount, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "0", style = "width:70px;", @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdultCount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ChildCount, htmlAttributes: new { style = "text-align:left", @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-2 input-group">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ChildCount, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "0", style = "width:70px;", @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ChildCount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery code that adds a new client side validation rule to the PaxCount input:

```
$.validator.addMethod("checkPaxCount",
    function (value, element, params) {
        $.validator.messages.checkPaxCount = jQuery.validator.format("Passenger count must be the sum of the no. of adults and children.");
        var chCount = parseInt($('#ChildCount').val());
        var adCount = parseInt($('#AdultCount').val());
        return parseInt(value) == chCount + adCount;
    },
    $.validator.messages.checkPaxCount
);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#PaxCount').rules('add',
        {
            checkPaxCount: true,
            messages: {
                checkpaxCount: "Error: ChildCount + AdultCount must = PaxCount"
            }
});
```

This works perfectly in Chrome, however when I try it in IE11, for some reason, the PaxCount field becomes a required field. To solve this, I added `required: false,` to the list of rules in my function, and it was fixed. However, once I did this, then the AdultCount field below became required instead. So I added a new rule to this input as well:

```
$('#AdultCount').rules('add',
{
    required: false,
});
```

and the same thing happened again, the ChildCount field below *that* becomes required. So on and so forth, the effect continues throughout the form. It can be solved by adding a rule to every field, but I'm just wondering why this happens, and if there is perhaps a more elegant solution?

Just in case it is needed, here is the code (utilising DataAnnotations) for the relevant fields in the model the form uses:

```
    [Display(Name = "No. of Passengers")]
    [Range(1,20, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 1 and 20.")]
    public int PaxCount { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "No. of Adults")]
    [Range(1, 20, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 1 and 20.")]
    public int AdultCount { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "No. of Children")]
    [Range(0, 20, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 0 and 20.")]
    public int ChildCount { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because your custom rule does not allow the field to be empty.

In order to have a custom rule on an "optional" field, you need to include an "OR" `this.optional(element)`

Modify it as follows...

```
$.validator.addMethod("checkPaxCount",
    function (value, element, params) {
        $.validator.messages.checkPaxCount = jQuery.validator.format("Passenger count must be the sum of the no. of adults and children.");
        var chCount = parseInt($('#ChildCount').val());
        var adCount = parseInt($('#AdultCount').val());
        return this.optional(element) || (parseInt(value) == chCount + adCount);
    },
    $.validator.messages.checkPaxCount
);
```